# How to deploy a Play 2.0 app on Debian?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, debian, playframework-2.2

I have play application, to make it easy to deploy on Debian,
What are the ways to

1. Create a daemon out of the code, with a standard init.d script, the main problem here how to gracefully stop the application?
2. How can I compile the code as a fat jar, easy to maintain 1 single file compared to multiple files and directories (the standard way of deploying a Play app).

Answer (score 9):

1. assuming you are using the "play dist" package, you could create a simple init.d script around it.  Something like:

/etc/init.d/play.myplayapp

```
    #! /bin/sh

    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          play
    # Required-Start:    $all
    # Required-Stop:     $all
    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    # Short-Description:
    # Description:
    ### END INIT INFO

    APP="myplayapp"
    APP_PATH="/opt/play/$APP"

    start() {
        $APP_PATH/start &
    }

    stop() {
        kill `cat $APP_PATH/RUNNING_PID`
    }

    case "$1" in
      start)
        echo "Starting $APP"
        start
        echo "$APP started."
        ;;
      stop)
        echo "Stopping $APP"
        stop
        echo "$APP stopped."
        ;;
      restart)
        echo  "Restarting $APP."
        stop
        sleep 2
        start
        echo "$APP restarted."
        ;;
      *)
        N=/etc/init.d/play.$APP
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

2. They don't really have a single file distribution of projects.  The best you can do is running "play dist" to generate a distributable package.  Even if it was distributed as a single file, it would probably be extracted to the file system at runtime just for efficiency (just how war files are handled).

Comment: FatJar's are not expanded at runtime. I was looking for an option to build a fatJar.

Comment: This script would work most of the times, but for the odd time when `kill` would fail. Could be in a bad state then. The PID, file is gone and the app is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared new version of script compatible with play 2.2.x packages:

https://github.com/mgosk/play-app-deamon

```
 #! /bin/sh

    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          play
    # Required-Start:    $all
    # Required-Stop:     $all
    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    # Short-Description:
    # Description:
    ### END INIT INFO

    # configurable variables
    APP_NAME="myplayapp"
    APP_DIR="/opt/myplayapp"
    CONF="application.conf"

    # private variables
    APP_SCRIPT="$APP_DIR/bin/$APP_NAME"
    PID_FILE="/var/run/$APP_NAME.pid"
    CONF_FILE="$APP_DIR/conf/$CONF"

    start() {
         $APP_SCRIPT -Dpidfile.path=$PID_FILE -Dconfig.file=$CONF_FILE  > /dev/null &
    }

    stop() {
        kill `cat $PID_FILE`
    }

    case "$1" in
      start)
        echo "Starting $APP_NAME"
        if [ -e "$PID_FILE" ] ; then
                echo "$APP_NAME already running"
                echo "Try restart option or delete pid file at $PID_FILE"
        else
                start
                echo "$APP_NAME started"
        fi
        ;;
      stop)
        echo "Stopping $APP_NAME"
        stop
        echo "$APP_NAME stopped."
        ;;
      restart)
        echo  "Restarting $APP_NAME"
        stop
        sleep 2
        start
        echo "$APP_NAME restarted."
        ;;
      status)
        if [ -e "$PID_FILE" ] ; then
                echo "$APP_NAME is running (pid `cat $PID_FILE`)"
        else
                echo "$APP_NAME is not running"
        fi
        ;;
      *)
        N="/etc/init.d/$APP_NAME"
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```